# Solve this ODE by fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-transform

> Find a continuous solution satisfying:
>   $$
> \frac{dy}{dx} +y= f(x)
> $$
>   Where
>   $$ 
> f(x) =  \begin{cases} 1  &\text{ for } 0 < x < 1, \\
> 0 & \text{ for } x > 1 \end{cases} 
> $$ 
>   with the initial condition $y(0)=0$. 
>    With use of the Fourier Transform

I understand the definition of the Fourier transform, and have found it for $f(x)$:

$F(x) = \frac{i}{k}\cdot (1 -e^{-ik})$

But I'm not sure how to then solve the *ODE* using this?

Can someone please help me with the next steps to find a solution please.

Comment: You need to know how the FT of a derivative relates to the FT of the function itself.

Comment: You should always link to your previous questions on the same topic, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2515166/115115, to avoid duplication of answers and to provide context.

Comment: This sort of thing is usually approached with the (related) Laplace transform/

Comment: I can't use Laplace unfortunately @copper.hat

Comment: Fourier can be applied to non homogenous ODE’s just as well, why are we telling him to use Laplace when he’s clearly been asked to use Fourier?

Comment: No one is telling him to do anything. Chill out. There are more technicalities to deal with since you have the negative part of the real line as well and the initial condition requires some care, in general.

Comment: @DaveNine thanks for the help, but its *her haha

Answer (score 1):

Denote the fouriertransform of $y$ for $\hat{y}$ then the fourierstransform of $y'$ is $2\pi i t \hat{y}$, so  your ODE becomes

$$
2\pi i t \hat{y}(t) + \hat{y}(t) = - \frac{i- ie^{-2\pi i t}}{2t\pi}
$$

Where $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-it2\pi x} dx = - \frac{i- ie^{-2\pi i t}}{2t\pi}$

Now you can solve for $\hat{y}$ and use the inverse fouriertransform.

Comment: How did you get the left hand side?

Comment: Using the roules for fouriertransform of derivative. @mathshelp101

Comment: Thats great help thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Proceeding informally, suppose $y, y'$ have Fourier transforms, then,
depending on your definition of the Fourier transform we have
$(1+ i \omega) \hat{y}(\omega) = {1 \over i \omega}(1-e^{-i \omega})$
and so
$\hat{y}(\omega) = {1 \over i \omega (1 + i \omega)} (1-e^{-i \omega}) $.

A little bit of work shows that
$y(x) = u(x)(1-e^{-x}) - u(x-1)(1-e^{-(x-1)})$.

In this case, for $x  \le 0$ we know that there is a unique solution to the differential equation ($x \mapsto 0)$ and for

Comment: Could you explain how you got this please?

Comment: Take the Fourier transform of both sides or the differential equation. The Fourier transform of the derivative is $i \omega$ multiplied by the Fourier transform of the function. The Fourier transform of $f$ can be computed directly from the definition.

Comment: To do the inversion, you will need to use the fact that $y(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$. This ends up being essentially the same as using the Laplace transform. However, implicitly I have used the fact that there is a unique solution to the differential equation, so the above informal approach is sweeping a number of details under the mathematical rug.

Comment: Thank you, thats a lot of help!!

Comment: @copper.hat Doesnt it follow from the fourier inversion theorem, and banach fix point theorem?

Comment: @Olba12: One you know the transform exists then you can apply inversion, table, etc.